# Is there a way to join the lists in python

Tags: python, list

I'm eager to know is there any way to join tow or more lists into one?

Please help me with this.

```
li= ["v1", "v2", "v3"]
l2= [1,2,3]
print(joined_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append two or more lists into one list by using the methods below.

- Using "+" operator
  Example:

```
li1= ["v1","v2","v3"]
li2= [1,2,3]
joined_list= li1+li2
print(joined_list)
```

output:

```
['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 1, 2, 3]
```

- Using list append function
  Example:

```
joined_list= []
li1= ["v1","v2","v3"]
li2= [1,2,3]

joined_list.append(li1)
joined_list.append(li2)

print(joined_list)
```

Output:

```
[['v1', 'v2', 'v3'], [1, 2, 3]]
```

- You can also use list extend function.

The parameters should be only iterables.

Example:

```
joined_list= []
li1= ["v1","v2","v3"]
li2= [1,2,3]

joined_list.extend(li1)
joined_list.extend(li2)

print(joined_list)
```

Output:

```
['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 1, 2, 3]
```